# Why returnValueMap() is returning NULL

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, phpunit, php-7

Trying to mock a doctrine repository inside a test, the returnValueMap() is always returning NULL when used with the *findOneBy* method.

I have mocked two entities then tried to mock their repository with a given return value map. The test fails and debugging shows that the returnValueMap() is returning NULL.

Here is the class to be tested (the denormalizer)

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Serializer;

use App\Entity\AdditionalService;
use App\Repository\AdditionalServiceRepository;
use Dto\AdditionalServiceCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DenormalizerInterface;

class AdditionalServiceCollectionDenormalizer implements DenormalizerInterface
{
    /** @var AdditionalServiceRepository */
    private $additionalServiceRepository;

    public function __construct(AdditionalServiceRepository $additionalServiceRepository)
    {
        $this->additionalServiceRepository = $additionalServiceRepository;
    }

    public function denormalize($mappedCsvRow, $class, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        $addtionalServicesCollection = new AdditionalServiceCollection();
        foreach ($mappedCsvRow as $fieldName => $fieldValue) {
            /** @var AdditionalService $additionalService */
            $additionalService = $this->additionalServiceRepository->findOneBy(['name'=>$fieldName]);

            if ($additionalService) {
                $addtionalServicesCollection->add($additionalService->getId(), $fieldValue);
            }
        }

        return $addtionalServicesCollection;
    }

    public function supportsDenormalization($data, $type, $format = null)
    {
        return $type instanceof  AdditionalServiceCollection;
    }
}
```

Here is my test class:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Tests\Import\Config;

use App\Entity\AdditionalService;
use App\Repository\AdditionalServiceRepository;
use App\Serializer\AdditionalServiceCollectionDenormalizer;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use Dto\AdditionalServiceCollection;

class AddionalServiceCollectionDenormalizerTest extends TestCase
{
    public function provider()
    {
        $expected = new AdditionalServiceCollection();
        $expected->add(1, 22.1)->add(2, 3.1);

        return [
            [['man_1' => 22.1], $expected],
            [['recycling' => 3.1], $expected],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @dataProvider provider
     * @covers \App\Serializer\AdditionalServiceCollectionDenormalizer::denormalize
     */
    public function testDenormalize(array $row, AdditionalServiceCollection $exptected)
    {
        $manOneService = $this->createMock(AdditionalService::class);
        $manOneService->expects($this->any())->method('getId')->willReturn(1);

        $recycling = $this->createMock(AdditionalService::class);
        $recycling->expects($this->any())->method('getId')->willReturn(2);

        $additionalServicesRepoMock = $this
            ->getMockBuilder(AdditionalServiceRepository::class)
            ->setMethods(['findOneBy'])
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();
        $additionalServicesRepoMock
            ->expects($this->any())
            ->method('findOneBy')
            ->will($this->returnValueMap(
                [
                    ['name'=>['man_1'], $manOneService],
                    ['name'=>['recycling'], $recycling],
                ]
            ));

        $denormalizer = new AdditionalServiceCollectionDenormalizer($additionalServicesRepoMock);

        self::assertEquals($exptected, $denormalizer->denormalize($row, AdditionalServiceCollection::class));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a hard time debugging the PHPUnit library, to figure out finally that it is the findOneBy() method that expects two arguments, among which the second one is optional (set to null)

The willReturnMap() method is as follows:

```php
/**
 * Stubs a method by returning a value from a map.
 */
class ReturnValueMap implements Stub
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $valueMap;

    public function __construct(array $valueMap)
    {
        $this->valueMap = $valueMap;
    }

    public function invoke(Invocation $invocation)
    {
        $parameterCount = \count($invocation->getParameters());

        foreach ($this->valueMap as $map) {
            if (!\is_array($map) || $parameterCount !== (\count($map) - 1)) {
                continue;
            }

            $return = \array_pop($map);

            if ($invocation->getParameters() === $map) {
                return $return;
            }
        }

        return;
    }
```

I suspected  the method was always returning with null because of the unmet condition  `$parameterCount !== (\count($map) - 1)`. 
A breakpoint confirmed my doubts, and also revealed that `$invocation->getParameters()` dumps as follows:

```php
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(1) {
    'name' =>
    string(5) "man_1"
  }
  [1] =>
  NULL
}
```

Hence, I had to explicitely pass `null` as second argument.
So finally the working map had to be:

```php
$this->additionalServicesRepoMock
            ->method('findOneBy')
            ->willReturnMap([
                [['name' => 'man_1'], null, $manOneService],
                [['name' => 'recycling'], null, $recyclingService],
            ]);
```

Comment: I had the same hard time, and then realized that Doctrine EntityRepository implements an interface called ObjectRepository. The ObjectRepository method findOneBy has only a single argument:

`public function findOneBy(array $criteria);`

but EntityRepository implementation has two arguments:

`public function findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the parameter of `returnValueMap()` in `testDenormalize()` needs brackets to make it indexed array.

Here's a slightly modified version of code snippet from [the PHPUnit's document](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.1/test-doubles.html#test-doubles-stubs-examples-stubtest5-php):

```
<?php

namespace App\Tests;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class ReturnValueMapTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testReturnValueMapWithAssociativeArray()
    {
        $stub = $this->createMock(SomeClass::class);

        $map = [
            [
                'name' => ['man_1'],
                'Hello'
            ],
        ];

        $stub->method('doSomething')
            ->will($this->returnValueMap($map));

        // This will fail as doSomething() returns null
        $this->assertSame('Hello', $stub->doSomething(['name' => ['man_1']]));
    }

    public function testReturnValueMapWithIndexedArray()
    {
        $stub = $this->createMock(SomeClass::class);

        $map = [
            [
                ['name' => ['man_1']], // Notice the difference
                'Hello'
            ],
        ];

        $stub->method('doSomething')
            ->will($this->returnValueMap($map));

        $this->assertSame('Hello', $stub->doSomething(['name' => ['man_1']]));
    }
}

class SomeClass
{
    public function doSomething()
    {}
}
```

Comment: I tried the solution but it doesn't work. Actually, the findOneBy() method takes an associative array as a parameter, not an indexed one.

Comment: I meant `returnValueMap()` should take an indexed array. Though I've confirmed that `public function doSomething($parameterA, $parameterB = null)` would also break `testReturnValueMapWithIndexedArray()`. It's not super intuitive, I must say. Assuming `findOneBy()` is from Doctrine.